We are getting someplace/somewhere
During communication with the manager,

He asked, "Did you send email?"


I replied, "Yes, a long time ago"

Then he replied

"We are getting someplace/somewhere now".

But, I was expecting Good or Ok.
What exactly does it mean?
Thanks for suggestions and clarification and appreciated for your time.

If your description is word-for-word, that is everyday conversation. The boss complimented you on your current work, not just on sending that email. You anticipated the need, and the boss noticed you didn't need to be asked. Much better than Okay.

A couple of other edits to help you: (1) "During communication with my (or the) manager"; (2) "What exactly does it mean?"

@PeterKirkpatrick, Thank you and appreciated. Email is about the progress of the department, I was assigned by supreme command, But Manager was expecting me to share information that is purely my thoughts. Then at the end he said that sentence.

'Some place', or more likely 'someplace' (one word) is American for 'somewhere'; if we are getting somewhere we are making progress. Could be praise or sarcasm depending on what has happened in the past.

[corrections: During communication with my manager//a long time ago]

@NadeemLearningCenter-Online, I understand the flow of your question. My previous comment was to help you with the wording. Read again your post, and replace sentences 1 and 4 with my suggestions. Then it will read better to English speakers.

To make a few corrections:
He asked, "Did you send the email?"
I replied, "Yes, a long time ago."
Then he replied, "Now we're getting somewhere."
It means that, since you sent the email, now you're making progress.

Thank you All for helping.

@NadeemLearningCenter-Online it might also help to understand that 'getting somewhere' is opposed to 'getting nowhere'.

@JimmyJames, is this same understanding as explained by Michael Harvey. "Could be praise or sarcasm depending on what has happened in the past."
